# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid - LOV Cascade

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Grid with 2 Select List columns (LOV):

```
Type_of_food    Product
```

As per customer request both have their own independent table like this:

```
Type_of_food    type_of_food_Id
Fruit           123
Vegetable       456
Snack           789

Product         Product_Id   type_of_food_Id
Apple           ABC          123
Banana          DEF          123
Onion           GHI          456
Kale            JKL          456
Cookies         MNO          789
```

So basically, when the user selects Fruit from the drop down, the next column (Product) will be updated with the Products belonging to this category.
My Type_of_food column query is:

```
select distinct
type_of_food d,
type_of_food r
from type_of_food_table
```

While my Product column query is:

```
select distinct
Product r,
Product g
from Product_table
left join type_of_food_table on type_of_food_table.type_of_food_id = 
Product_table.type_of_food_id
```

Both LOV show Type_of_food and Product Items and when I select a Type_of_food the Product Column gets refreshed. Issue is, it doesn't get refreshed with the proper values (e.g. If I select Fruits it will show all Products regardless of Type).
My Product column has the 'Cascading List of Values' turned on with 'Parent Column(s)' = 'Type_of_food'.
Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, added this to the Product query:

```
select distinct
Product r,
Product g
from Product_table
left join type_of_food_table on type_of_food_table.type_of_food_id = 
Product_table.type_of_food_id
--getting the select list column (product) value:
where type_of_food_table.type_of_food = v('type_of_food_select_list_column')
```